# Piecewize Python CPlex

Tags: python, linear-programming, cplex

This is my optimization problem :

My company sells 2 items A and B, res 20$ and 30$.

- If the production of A > 0, then the cost of maintenance is 20
- If the production of A > 200, then the cost of maintenance is 30
- If the production of A > 300, then the cost of maintenance is 50

How to maximize my profit ?

There are discontinuous piecewize constraints.

How should I model this using Cplex ?
There is my first try out, using **binary** variables :
This is not working when a >= 300:

```
DOcplexException: Model did not solve successfully
```

Complete code, using  **binary**  variables :

```
import cplex
import docplex.mp
from docplex.mp.model import Model

model = Model(name='LP_example')

a = model.integer_var(name='a')
b = model.integer_var(name='b')
z = model.binary_var(name='z')
k = model.binary_var(name='k')
t = model.binary_var(name='t')

model.maximize(20 * a + 30 * b - z * 20 + k * 30 + t *  50 )

model.add_constraint(a + b <= 1000)
model.add_constraint(a >= 200)
model.add_constraint(b >= 150)

model.add_constraint(model.if_then(a <= 200, z == 1))
model.add_constraint(model.if_then(a >= 200, k == 1))
model.add_constraint(model.if_then(a >= 300, k == 0))
model.add_constraint(model.if_then(a >= 300, t == 1))

model.solve()

for v in model.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value) 

for v in model.iter_binary_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

How to use the **model.piecewize** function ?

Edit : I have something based on this exemple : https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoopiecewise.py

What do you think about that ?

```
f = model.piecewise(0, [(0, 0),(200,200)], z==1)

model.maximize(f(a) * 20 +  b * 30 - z * 20 )
```

Thanks a lot Sebastian, with your help, I have found this :

```
# Define the piecewise linear function
f = model.piecewise(0, [(0, 20), (200, 30), (300, 50)],1)

model.maximize(20 * a - f(a) + 30 * b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for the piecewise function are hard to find but I found them by installing the `docplex` package.
In the source code we find the following docstring:

```
 def piecewise(self, preslope, breaksxy, postslope, name=None):
        """  Adds a piecewise linear function (PWL) to the model, using breakpoints to specify the function.

        Args:
            preslope: Before the first segment of the PWL function there is a half-line; its slope is specified by
                        this argument.
            breaksxy: A list `(x[i], y[i])` of coordinate pairs defining segments of the PWL function.
            postslope: After the last segment of the the PWL function there is a half-line; its slope is specified by
                        this argument.
            name: An optional name."""
```

Therefore you should use `piecewise` like this for your usecase:

```
f = model.piecewise(0, [(0, 20), (200, 30), (300, 50)], 50)

model.maximize(20 * a - f(a) + 30 * b)
```

The 50 in particular is the slope for `a > 300`. If you have a 1 there it's incorrectly modelled.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I have modified the original text to "maintenance" costs , that is more logical. The more you product, the more maintenance costs are high.

Comment: I removed the chatgpt parts. the answer is more concise this way anyway